# A basic doubt on a problem on sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose a sequence of "distinct" elements $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ and $x$ is not in the sequence. Then given an $N$ can we find an $\epsilon >0$ s.t. there exists $M >N$ with the property that $\forall n \geq M$ $|x_n-x| <\epsilon$ and the set $\{x_n:n\geq M\} = \{x_n:|x_n-x| < \epsilon\}$ ? This looks intuitively possible, but I am not able to formally write it.

Actually, I want to find an $\epsilon >0$ such that all the points in the sequence which are $\epsilon$ distance apart from $x$ are some $x_n$ where $n > N$ and $N$ is the given integer. Because I can get rid of the points before $x_N$ by choosing $\epsilon<min(x_i,x); i <N$ it looks like it is possible to find such an $\epsilon$

In other words, given an $N$ I want to find an $\epsilon$ such that all the sequence elements starts becoming less than $\epsilon$ distance apart after $N$. Am I making sense now ?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Given $N$ I want to find an $\epsilon$ as stated above.

Comment: Why don't you choose $\epsilon=2M$ regardless of $N$, where $|x_n|<M$ for all $n$? All sequence elements are now less then $\epsilon$ apart.

Comment: @Shahab: What is $M$ ?. I have been given a sequence $\{x_n\}$ and $N$. Answer should be in of terms of $N$.

Comment: You say that the sequence converges. Hence it must be bounded and so such an $M$ will definitely exist.

Comment: @Shahab: I want a collection of points which are less than $\epsilon$ distance apart from $x$, but I want to take only the points after the given integer $N$ into account. I can't take all the points of the sequence by choosing a large value for $\epsilon$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10726/discussion-between-shahab-and-prasenjit)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so firstly the definition of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ is that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$. I write this as the title mentions confusion regarding the definition.

What you write is not equivalent to the definition, for instance take the sequence $0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots$ and take $N=2$. Then no matter how small (or big) you pick $\epsilon>0, \{x_n\,:\,|x_n-x|<\epsilon\}$ always contains $0=x_1$, however for each $M>N$, $\{x_n\,:\, n>M\}$ does not contain $0$. So these sets aren't equal.

Comment: Indeed the sequences for which this property is true seem to be exactly those for which $|x_n - x|$ is decreasing.

Comment: Or just plain old monotonic.

Comment: in $\mathbb R$, sure.

Comment: @James: I forgot to mention that $x$ does not belong to the sequence.

Comment: @all: It looks intuitively clear that if I choose $\epsilon$ very very small then i can make sure that all the points in the sequence which are less than $\epsilon$ distance apart from $x$ lies in the right side of $x$. This we can do because when we say "there exist an N" in the definition of convergence then this $N$ is actually $N_\epsilon$. So, the main job is to express $\epsilon$ in terms of $N$

Comment: On second thought there are certainly sequences satisfying this that aren't monotonic... e.g. 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/3, ... requires some more thought.

Comment: It's still not true, however: consider $\frac12, 1, \frac13, \frac12, \frac14, \frac13, \frac15, \frac14 \ldots$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: If I can cover all the elements less than $\epsilon$ distance apart from $x$ in the sequence  I will be happy. If there is some repeatation in the sequence I have already taken them into account. Is it possible now ?

Answer (score 0):

This is as per your statement:

> In other words, given an $N$ I want to find an $\epsilon$ such that all the sequence elements starts becoming less than $\epsilon$ distance apart after $N$.

There is no way to find such an epsilon you are looking for unless you take $\epsilon=2M$ where $|x_n|<M$ for all $n>N$, for there is no guarantee that $|x_{N+i}-x_{N+j}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: still not convinced. Can you give one counterexample ? which satisfies all the criteria but does not give such $\epsilon$. Does not it look intuitively possible ?

Comment: @prasenjit: Suppose it was possible. Take any sequence $(a_n)$ for which such an $\epsilon(N)$ has been found. Now construct another sequence $(b_n)$ in which the $N+1$th term and the $N+2$th term are more then $\epsilon(N)$ apart, and other then these two terms the rest are same as in $(a_n)$.